# Create a new DAC : naming advice

Tags: acumatica

I just have one question to make sure I'm doing it the right way.
When creating a field in an existing DAC, the system automatically adds the prefix "usr". From what I understand, this allows Acumatica to know that the field is specific and that it must be kept during a version upgrade.

> When we create a new table / DAC (I've never done this before and I'm going to need to), should we add the prefix "usr" as well? If we don't add it, will the specific DAC be taken into account when upgrading?

Thank you in advance for your advice.
(And sorry for my english...)

Comment: I know nothing about Acumatica but your English is better than some native speakers!

Comment: Hey very nice !! Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your DAC name would be prefaced by your Acumatica registered prefix if you are building a vertical for the marketplace as an ISV. For customizations best practice is to use a 2 digit identifier that is an abbreviation related to the tenant followed by the module. For example MTSVCalc could be a calculation table in the service module for My Tenant. More on naming conventions https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=74ee714c-b70a-4f67-8647-329c5b774b2c

Comment: Perfect thank you very much !! That's what I thought, but I preferred to have confirmation. Only fields in existing DACs should be prefixed with "usr".
For the rest it is necessary to keep the usual naming.
Thank you for the link to the documentation, I missed the part concerning the naming !!
Thanks again !!

Comment: Those are best practices and help the framework tools. For example UsrFields shows fields in customized tabs based on prefix. Even though it's recommended to follow the conventions there is no enforced limitation on naming.